# Unit testing useLoaderData() react-router v6 loader functions

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router

A project uses react-router v6 and in some components I call `useLoaderData()`. For instance:

```js
const routes = [
    { path: "widgets", 
      loader: () => fetchAndGetJSON("/api/widgets"), 
      element: <ListWidgets/> }
];

function ListWidgets() {
    const widgets = useLoaderData();
    return <>
        <p>Here is a list of {widgets.length} widgets:
        <...>
    </>;
}
```

When testing I do not want to execute the `fetch`, I want to supply the list of widgets in the test.

How can I create a unit test for `ListWidgets` that uses data that I supply in the test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used React Router's data APIs myself, but as I understand it, there are three main alternatives.

1. Use Jest's standard mocking functionality to [mock `fetch`](https://www.leighhalliday.com/mock-fetch-jest), mock `fetchAndGetJSON`, or similar.

   ```
   global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
     Promise.resolve({
       json: () => Promise.resolve(FAKE_TEST_DATA),
     })
   );

   beforeEach(() => fetch.mockClear());
   ```
2. Use [`createMemoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-memory-router) with a testing version of your route that renders `<ListWidgets/>` with a custom  `loader` that returns the test data that you want.

   ```
   test(ListWidgets, async () => {
     const routes = [{
       path: "widgets",
       element: <ListWidgets />,
       loader: () => FAKE_TEST_DATA,
     }];

     const router = createMemoryRouter(routes, { initialEntries: ["widgets"] });

     render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
     // ...testing...
   }
   ```
3. Use [Mock Service Worker (msw.js)](https://mswjs.io/) to create a mock back-end. Functionally, this is pretty similar to mocking `fetch` yourself, but MSW is very good at streamlining and consolidating things.

   ```
   const worker = setupWorker(
     rest.get('/api/widgets', async (req, res, ctx) => {
       const { username } = await req.json();
       return res(ctx.json(FAKE_TEST_DATA))
     }),
   );

   worker.start();
   ```

I'm a big fan of msw.js, but any of the options should work. (It's something of a trade-off: overriding `loader` results in more narrowly target unit tests, while msw.js lets you write less invasive tests closer to the integration testing end of the spectrum.)

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions! I will likely go with option 2.